# Android::Creating a clickable collage?

Tags: android, design-patterns, android-widget

I am trying to create something like a rectangular grid with pictures. When a picture is clicked, it should zoom in pushing the other ones out. I don't know what you name you call this particular model with but does anyone have suggestions on where I should start?

[Collage Example](http://olliebray.typepad.com/.a/6a00d8341eb53c53ef0112793e5d3428a4-300wi)

Answer (score 0):

To start with, I'd read up on layouts in android:  [developer docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html) are always a good place to start.  A GridView might work well for you.

[Handling UI events](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html) should get you started in listening for mouse clicks.

I'd start with something simple, just showing the pictures on the screen, and then you can build up to more complicated animations, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at android-collage-views:Draggable, rotatable, and scalable views for Android
https://github.com/thuytrinh/android-collage-views